# Angular blank page without error

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run basic Angular 5 app from Visual Studio 2013.

I've created Web api project and I ran the following command from root directory:

`ng new testclient`

Now when I run following command:

`ng serve --o`

Angular app run perfectly.

But when I try to run the application from visual studio it gives me blank page without any errors, I use following URL to run:

`localhost:5801/testclient/src`

Comment: Tried to go to `localhost:5801` ?

Comment: yes I tried but it gives HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error